# Stop video autoplay on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, html5-video, autoplay

If you go to my site:

```
http://www.crookedfoothuntclub...
```

On mobile you will here the video play in the background. I have set the visibility to false on bigger screen-sizes and I was hoping that this would not only hide the video but prevent it from loading all together hence saving the end user bandwidth and load time. (Please keep this in mind on the primary objective I would like to accomplish).

As a stop gap I have tried to at least prevent the autoplay of the video by adding some custom JS.

The class name of the video on my home page is:

```
home-video
```

Here is the script I'm trying to use:

```
<script>
if($(window).width() >= 786){
    var vid = document.getElementsByClassName("home-video");
    vid.autoplay = false;
    vid.load();
}
</script>
```

Currently the effect I'm going for is not happening and I need some help getting this to work. 
If you know a better way to achieve the effect I'm asking about please consider me open to that approach in correcting the current situation.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` gets an array of elements.  You need to parse that array and set `autoplay` to false on all of them, of if there's only 1, change it to.. `var vid = document.getElementsByClassName("home-video")[0];`

Comment: Updated code:

<script>
if($(window).width() >= 786){
    var vid = document.getElementsByClassName("home-video")[0]
    vid.autoplay = false;
    vid.load();
}
</script>

Right?

Comment: Just tried it out doesn't seem to stop the auto play on a mobile device

Comment: Found out the element id and changed the code to:
<script>
if($(window).width() >= 765){
    var vid = document.getElementById("video-container-7")    
    vid.autoplay = false;
    vid.load();
}
</script>

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the issue and try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Detectizr](https://baris.aydinoglu.info/Detectizr/) for your requirement and in if condition for mobile devices as `vid.autoplay = false;` and for desktop make it `vid.autoplay = true;`.

Thanks